# SSRS report refreshes through I have 'never refresh' set for all parameters

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, refresh, reportbuilder3.0

I have 2 date/time parameters, to and from. From was set to `=DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -1, Today())`. And the other, to, was set to just `=Today()`.

When I view the report, the default values are populated correctly and the report is generated correctly on first load. However, when I change the from date field, the report refreshes. If I change just the to field, it does not refresh.

Reading other suggestions on other sites, someme people mentioned creating a new dataset with something like `Select GetDate() as Date` and then using that as the default value of my parameter, but that didn't work. Another was creating an internal parameter and setting it's default value to `=Today()` and then using that value as my parameter's default - again, didn't work.

Anything else I might try?

Answer (score 1):

More searching gave me my answer:

> @Piquet - Your solution appears to be correct...at least in my case which seems similar to most of the other posts. I was using default values for date parameters that were expressions - "=Today()" and "=DateAdd("yyyy",-5,Today())". And no matter what I tried when changing the value of the report's first parameter would cause a page refresh that generated a blank/report.
>
> I testing changing all parameters default to No Default where they were using expressions and viola no blank page refresh. To get back the default date values I'm now using a dataset like this:
>
> Select CONVERT(date,(DateAdd("yyyy",-5,GETDATE()))) AS default_start, CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) AS default_end
>   The blank page refresh is gone when changing the value of the parameters and the default date values are working fine.
>
> Thanks for the post as it seemed an elusive problem. David

From [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6e5c4137-092f-4d54-a1a1-27730744074d/changing-default-parameters-cause-postbackrefresh) MSDN thread.

There's also a lot of information in that thread about how if you have two parameters, the second one is assumed to be dependant on the first if they both have expressions:

> For example, if you have a report with Param1 and Param2, RS will assume Param2 depends on Param1 if:
>
> - Param2 is populated from a query that uses certain types of
>     expressions for query text, query parameters, calculated fields,
>     filters, etc.
> - Param2 is populated from one or more expressions.